# Android: Как в адаптер передать два массива?

Tags: массивы, android, listview, java, adapter

Смысл в том, что у меня есть `ListView`. Я создала меню. Хочу, что бы были подписи. Меню кликабельное и рабочее.

```
public class MainMenu extends ListActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle cicle) {

    super.onCreate(cicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_main);

    String[] catnames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cat_names);

    // String[] catnames1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.label1); - здесь у меня второй массив с подписями.        

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label, catnames);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Intent intent = null;

    switch (position) {

    case 0:
        intent = new Intent(this, AboutStudio.class);
        break;
    case 1:
        intent = new Intent(this, Works.class);
        break;
    case 2:
        intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
        break;

    case 3:
        intent = new Intent(this, News.class);
        break;

    case 4:
        intent = new Intent(this, Contacts.class);
        break;

    case 5:
        intent = new Intent(this, Team.class);
        break;
    case 6:
        intent = new Intent(this, GoogMap.class);
        break;

    }
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

Как мне в адаптер передать два массива?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте свой класс, который наследует от BaseAdapter, либо ArrayAdapter. У своего класса создайте конструктор который принимает ваши два массива и реализуйте остаточный функционал.

Answer (score 0):

Пишите свой адаптер